# Password authentication failed for user "zabbix"

Tags: postgresql, debian, zabbix

I have an issue with new zabbix installation.
Debian 11, zabbix 6.2, postgresql.
I have done all actions acording the official manual, but have an error:

47553:20230630:062259.755 [Z3001] connection to database 'zabbix' failed: [0] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "zabbix"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "zabbix"

I checked the password in /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf and in postgresql, they are the same and I even changed them to another one.

"zabbix" user is superuser in postgresql.

What should I check next? I don't get it, how it's possible. Of course, I restarted DB service and zabbix service...

Comment: Can the zabbix user connect to postgresql through a client program?

Comment: Check the postgresql log file

Comment: Checked log - 2023-06-29 09:49:29.954 EDT [24740] zabbix@zabbix FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "zabbix"
2023-06-29 09:49:29.954 EDT [24740] zabbix@zabbix DETAIL:  Password does not match for user "zabbix".
        Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 98: "host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5"